# How to create a .xlsx file in C# with .NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

I managed to make the writing work with the .NET Framework 4.6.1 with following code I took from an online source:

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

class E
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {

            Excel.Application excel;
            Excel.Workbook workbook;
            Excel.Worksheet sheet;

            excel = new Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = true;

            workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add();
            sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

            sheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Number";
            sheet.Cells[1, 2] = "English";
            sheet.Cells[1, 3] = "German";
            sheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Formula";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message} Line: {e.Source}");
        }
    }
}
```

So what happens when I execute it with .NET Core 2.1 is, that it's opening Excel but does not write to the cells. The sheets are not readonly, which I checked.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: On which OS is it running? Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel is compatible on Windows only and the machine needs to have Excel installed

Comment: I see the same issue, upgrade to .NET Core 3.0 resolved it for me. But I don't know why it doesn't work in .NET Core 2.1 sorry.

Comment: Why you not calling save method ?

Comment: Maybe Kenan doesn't want to save the spreadsheet.... Saving is not required.

Comment: @WilliamW Yes, Windows with Excel installed.

Comment: @RyanThomas Tried it out with .NET Core 3.1, it works. Still wondering why it is not properly working with Core 2.1

Comment: @ManojChoudhari I do that actually in my code. But it still it isn't working to write. This shouldn't be the problem since saving would just create an empty file. But anyways, it is not required to save it.

Comment: @Kenan No I do not understand why it doesn't work either, I mean if upgrading is a suitable solution for you then I'd go with it. If not you may need to use something like dnSpy to try and work out what is falling over... but if it's deep in the interop/framework code then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @Kenan As an alternative if upgrading is not an option, you can use another nuget package which can read / write in excel (there are tons of them, I will let you google it. I have a preference for EPPlus)

Comment: @Kenan `sheet.Cells[1, 1]` returning null. Though your code is perfectly working in .net fw